# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to log in anonymously on my firebase, I have added all the needed stuff that shows in the FireBase page, but for some reason when I try to log in anonymously, I get this erro:

```
I/flutter ( 1656): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method signInAnonymously on 
channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
I/flutter ( 1656): Log in error
```

This is my sign in anonymously code, doesn't show me any errors on my page:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

//Definir os metodos que vao interagir com firebase
class AuthService {

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//Logar anonimamente
Future signInAnon() async {
try {
  AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
  FirebaseUser user = result.user;
  return user;
}catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

Calling it in main page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:homeautomation/services/auth.dart';

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
 final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
 ...
 Body:
 Child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Logar Anonimamente'),
      onPressed: () async {

        dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
        if (result == null)
          {
            print('erro ao logar');
          }
        else
          {
            print('Logado');
            print(result);
          }
      },
    ),
```

Restarted Android Studio, and I'm getting a different error now:

```
PlatformException(ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE, API: 
InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device. 
Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, 
resolution=null, message=null}, null)
I/flutter ( 2963): erro ao logar
```

Comment: Yes, I enabled Sing in anonymosly

Comment: Try cleaning your project with `flutter clean` and install the packages again with `flutter packages get` command

Comment: If you added package while app is running then it will give this error maybe. Try to flutter clean and run again.

Comment: I restarted the Android Studio, got a different error now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you enabled sign in anonymously in your `Firebase console`? 
If **NO**, you have to enable it in the `Firebase Console`.

If **YES**, run `flutter clean` and your code should be free from errors.

If `flutter clean` doesn't work,

> Check if the device you are running on has Google Play Services, if it does not. You have to install. it to stop seeing that error.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I enabled in my website, does that mean I enabled in the Firebase Console?

Comment: I'm getting a differnet type of erro now, PlatformException(ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE, API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}, null)
I/flutter ( 2963): erro ao logar

Comment: I did flutter clean, but i'm getting a new type of erro, I updated my question

Comment: Are you using an emulator? Does your emulator or device have Google play Services ?

Comment: I'm using genymotion

Comment: Does it have Google Play Services ? That might be the cause of the error

Comment: It doesn't apparently, gonna install it

Comment: That's is the issue. Don't forget to mark my answer correct and upvote. If it helps.

Comment: It worked, how do you know all these error hahaha been searcing it up earlier. Well Thanks, your really good!

Comment: Thank you ! Glad I was able to help.

Comment: cmd -> direct to your flutter projekt folder and run flutter clean worked perfect for me (and restarted VS-Code

Answer (score 2):

***Worked for me. Hope this will help.***

**Use following dependencies**

```
  firebase_core: '0.5.0'
  firebase_auth: "^0.18.0+1"
```

**Click** *Package get*

**Upgrade Plugins** in pubspec.yaml ( The plugins upgrade button will get appeared once you get into the yaml page.)

Comment: I needed to add firebase_core to my pub get to fix my issue! Thanks!